# String replace() returns extra space in Java

Tags: java, string, replace, char

Consider:

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[10]).replace("\0", "hello"));
```

has output:

```
hellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohellohello
```

but:

```
System.out.println(new String(new char[10]).replace("", "hello"));
```

has output:

```
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello
```

Where are these extra spaces coming from?

Comment: You should loop through the string and print each character.

Comment: @Ferrybig There was never a trailing space. The OP's original description was (presumably) incorrect. See for example https://ideone.com/492Cml.

Answer (score 15):

It is not a space. It is how your IDE/console ***shows*** [`\0`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0000/) character which `new char[10]` is filled with by default.

You are not replacing `\0` with anything, so it stays in string. Instead with `.replace("", "hello")` you are replacing only empty string `""`. Important thing is that Java assumes that `""` exists at:

- start of the string,
- end of string,
- and between each of the characters

since we can get `"abc"` with:

```
"abc" = "" + "a" + "" + "b" + "" + "c" + ""`;
      //^          ^          ^          ^
```

Now `.replace("", "hello")` replaces each of those `""` with `"hello"`, so for string of length 10 it will place additional **11** `hello`s (not **10**), without modifying `\0`, which will be *shown* at your output like spaces.

---

Maybe this will be easier to grasp:

```
System.out.println("aaa".replace("", "X"));
```

- lets represent each `""` with as `|`. We will get `"|a|a|a|"` (notice that there are 4 `|`)
- so replacing `""` with `X` will result in `"XaXaXaX"` (but in your case instead of `a` your console will print `\0` using character which will look like space)

Answer (score 12):

### Short version

`\0` represents character `NUL`, it does not equals empty string `""`.

### Long version

1. When you try to create a `String` with empty `char[10]`,:

   ```
   String input = new String(new char[10]);
   ```

   this `String` will contains 10 `NUL` character:

   ```
   |NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|NUL|
   ```
2. When you call `input.replace("\0", "hello")`, the `NUL` value(`\0`) will be replaced by `hello`:

   ```
   |hello|hello|hello|hello|hello|hello|hello|hello|hello|hello|
   ```
3. When you call `input.replace("", "hello")`, the `NUL` value will not be replaced since it does not match empty string `""`:

   ```
   |hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|NUL|hello|
   ```

Answer (score 8):

### Explanation

You are using the method `String#replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))).

If invoked with an empty target character sequence `replace("", replacement)` it will **not replace** the elements in the source, but **insert** the *replacement* before every character.

This is because `""` matches the positions between the characters, not the characters themselves. So every position between will be replaced, i.e. *replacement* is inserted.

Example:

```
"abc".replace("", "d") // Results in "dadbdcd"
```

Your string contains only the default value of `char` at every position, it is

```
\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0
```

using the method thus results in:

```
hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0hello\0
```

---

### Display

Your console probably displayed the character `\0` as *whitespace*, while it's actually not a *whitespace* but `\0`.

If I try out your code in a different console, I get:

[image]

Confirming that the characters are indeed not spaces but something different (i.e. `\0`).

Comment: `replace("", ...)` inserts the replacement at the end of the string too. See e.g. https://ideone.com/492Cml.

Answer (score 3):

`char`'s default value is `\u0000` which can also be represented as `\0`. So your `new char[10]` contains 10 `\0`s.

In the first statement you clearly replace `\0` with `"hello"`. But in the second statement you leave out the default value. Which your IDE output chooses to show as a space.